# Applying Gauss law between 2 mediums

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dielectric

[image]

Consider a closed Gaussian surface crossing the boundary of two different dielectric medium (assume that in a particular medium there's same relative permitivity everywhere) and also consider some point charges within the Gaussian surface.

My question is what do you multiply the $\epsilon_0$ with which is there in the "q(in) divided by $\epsilon_0$"

I mean Gauss' law works just fine if applied on a Gaussian surface completely contained in a single medium, if we just multiply the relative permitivity with the $\epsilon_0$ in [q(in) by $\epsilon_0$]

But what about a scenario like this one? It's just getting me confused.

Comment: FYI: It's [*naught*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naught), which simply means "zero" instead of "not".

Answer (score 1):

For linear media, you use Gauss’s law in a medium:

$$ \nabla\cdot D = \rho/\epsilon $$

Where $D$ is the displacement field.